# Why is Chrome Driver crashing or elements not located with Cron job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cron, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I've created a **scraper** using watir/mechanize and chrome driver, it works perfectly in development.
It was not working in production, chrome driver was crashing, so I had to add those lines at the beginning of my **scraper** (found them on another topic on stackoverflow)

```
 args = %w[--disable-infobars --disable-dev-shm-usage --headless --no- 
 sandbox --disable-gpu]
    options = {
     binary: ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN'],
     prefs: { password_manager_enable: false, 
     credentials_enable_service: false },
     args:  args
  }
  browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: options)
```

It now works great in production, even with my background job (I basically trigger the background job that is **scraping** by clicking on a button).

I also have another background job, a Cron job this time, which scrapes automatically once every two weeks.
But for some reason, this one does not work. I got the same error message I had before adding all the lines above

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed 
  to start: crashed (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't 
exist) 
 (The process started from chrome location /app/.apt/o...)
```

Sometimes I don't get this error message and the **scraper** starts with the Cron job (without me changing anything) but it just can't locate the elements I want (whereas it works everytime with the other background job, not using Cron and it is the exact same content)

Do you have any idea why there is a different behaviour when I am using a Cron job?
I would understand if I had the same error everywhere, but I don't get why it is only crashing or struggling to find my elements only when I am using Cron.
And last question: why are my errors changing all the time? Usually, I fix something and it works for a very long time, but with Selenium/ChromeDriver it just seems I have to update my code every 3 days!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For these kind of question please add selenium tag as well.

Comment: Sure :) That's done

Comment: The complete error stack trace _`The process started from chrome location /app/.apt/o...`_ would have been helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: Hello. I can't give it to you unfortunately as it is a cron job and sidekiq is not showing the full message.  Except if I can find it somewhere else?